# why is it mandatory to declare main method public...Why it is not possible for JVM to execute private main method

Tags: java

Generally I find in various books that main method should be public because it should be visible to classloader. But JVM executes(or provides special handling of) various private methods say readObject/writeObject method in ObjectOutputStream.

Comment: what benefit would there be for allowing a special case for the visibility of `main`? Why would you want a `private` or protected `main`?

Comment: The JVM does not have any special handling to call private methods from outside a class. The methods you named are all public. The only way you can bypass the visibility model is to use reflection, but this is wanted because it's purpose is to have deeper insight to objects.

Comment: @Mat I just want to know why part and what thinking could have been while defining spec, so I want to know that reason apart from keeping things simple simplicity

Comment: @Tobias P, I could not understand your point for static methods (as main is static method)...why there is need to call static methods from inside the class ? why not from outside ?  Again you said reflection....that is one option to call methods...but it adds complexity. So I want to know the reason apart from simplicity...is there any other reason behind it ?

Comment: My point and your question had nothing to do with static methods, you never spoke about static methods yet. And yes there's one point it has to be static: the specification says that when running a java program no object is created, so the only way to run code is to have the main-method statis. It's a languange decision. Scala specifies that an object is created so you do not need any static method. It's a specification somebody has written sometime with his own opinion on a good style, and for opinios there are sometimes no really reasons...

Comment: I understand the reason why main method is static ...."It's a specification somebody has written sometime with his own opinion on a good style, and for opinios there are sometimes no really reasons" << on this comment I think thats the point ...so no other reason for not allowing the main to be private. Its simply good design..less work while calling the main.... I take this..  Thanks all for your comments.

Answer (score 6):

It's pretty obvious that the entry point of your program should be visible.

Answer (score 2):

I guess because that's the way it is and that's the way the Java Language Specification decides it.  I can see why they have chosen the public access modifier, as you invoke the Java program from outside the Class (via command line) so it fits with Java's access control system that the main method should be public.

If the main method were allowed to be private, but then you have to invoke it from somewhere else e.g. java command line that would be contrary to Java's access modifiers.  It would be inconsistent behaviour, irrespective of whether or not it's technically possible.

Comment: private methods could be called from using reflection... so I dont think that declaring main as private breaks any fundamental...

Comment: @user(long number) - there might be a SecurityManager and just because it's technically possible does not mean it's the right thing or the right design

Comment: "If the main ... technically possible."  << on this comment I want to say that this wont be inconsistent behaviour. On you last comment I agree with you that this might be bad design. But I want to know apart from all this ...could there have been bigger problem by declaring method private ?

Comment: @planetjones Sorry for inconvenience caused.  @user(long number)  no longer exist ....Now name is more short n sweet ...no long number any more :)

Comment: @Ashish, private methods can be called w/ or w/o reflection, it's only the verifier that checks obeying java lang spec. it can be even turned off, or called from JNI or anything but can you explain what good a private method is going to do!?

Comment: @bestsss it could have done no harm either... (apart from being more complex calling of main method..) .  On the why I am interested in this is just a curiosity that.. could there have been bigger problem by declaring method private ?

Comment: @Ashish, it does extra harm as it prevents installing a (mini)-launcher that does some extra setup and then calls the true program via main() method. calling a static method from JNI makes no difference regarding the access modifiers.

Answer (score 2):

It is not mandatory to declare main() as public. We can declare it as private too. 
When a method is declared as private, the program compiles properly but it will give runtime error.
Main method not public

But if you declare main method as private, you would not be able to execute the class as a standalone java program. Any java class that needs to be executed as a standalone file needs to have a main method that is public, static and returns a void. Otherwise the Java compiler would not recognize the file as an executable standalone java file and would not allow you to run it.

```
 class A
{
int x=7;
void show(){
System.out.println(x);
}
}
class Test
{
private static void main(String args[])
{
A a = new A();
a.show();
}
}
```

will show an error

```
Main method not public
```